# Graphical artifact on a SVG circle stroke, IE and Firefox only (Windows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm having issues trying to remove a rather ugly artifact on my animated pie chart. It works perfectly fine on chrome, only ie (11 or edge) and firefox seem to have problems with it.

Let's start with a screenshot you will see immediately what is the problem :

**Ugly firefox version :**

[image]

**Perfect Chrome version :**

[image]

As you can see there is a very strange graphical bug on Firefox. I am unable to comprehend why is the rendering engine doing this.

edit : please note it's somehow related to the stroke width / svg elements dimensions

Let me explain what is actually happening here :

```
<figure id="pie" data-percentage="20" data-behavior="pie-chart">
  <svg>
    <!-- Radius has to be svg diameter divided by 4 -->
    <!-- Cx and cy have to be svg diameter divided by 2 -->
    <circle r="100" cx="100" cy="100"/>
    <circle r="50" cx="100" cy="100"/>
  </svg>
  <div class="receiver"></div>
</figure>
```

Basically I have a blue circle, no stroke. On top of it I have another blue circle, but with a green stroke. I animate the stroke dasharray thanks to js in order to "fill" the pie up to a given value, thus the animated pie chart.

But as you can see there is a big problem on non-webkit browsers. 
I am using the geometric precision of course in css.

[**You can see all my code on the codepen**](http://codepen.io/toplefty/pen/pgyjzr)

And here is just a minimal SVG version.

```css
svg {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

circle:nth-child(1) {
    fill: #4d80b3;
    stroke-width: 0;
}

circle:nth-child(2) {
    fill: #4d80b3;
    stroke: #9cc374;
    stroke-dasharray: 0, 314.159;
    stroke-width: 100px;
    transition: stroke-dasharray 2000ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0s;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <circle cy="100" cx="100" r="100"/>
    <circle cy="100" cx="100" r="50" style="stroke-dasharray: 62.8319, 314.159;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: For what it's worth in Firefox 41 I don't see this problem. (Or Firefox 43).  Perhaps you're using an old version of firefox that has a bug that is now fixed?

Comment: hi, are you sure ? maybe the percentage was hiding the problem. I deleted the percentage on codepen to avoid this

Comment: I also deleted the %.

Comment: That's strange, I have FF 43.0.2 and the issue is definitely visible

Comment: I'm on MacOS X - maybe it's a problem with a different OS?

Comment: yes I'm on windows 10 that might be related then

Comment: Confirming bug; `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-10 -10 20 20"><circle r="5" stroke-width="9" stroke="#000" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="2%" shape-rendering="crispEdges" /></svg>` in Firefox 43.0.2 64bit @ Win 7 produces this: (detail) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1571982/shots/Firefox-43.0.2-SVG-dasharray.png

Answer (score 3):

Using a `<path>` with `A` you can do it in the following way:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="210" width="210" >
<g transform="scale(2) translate(51,51)">
<path style="fill:#4d80b3" d="M 0,-50 A 50,50 0 1 0 47.55,-15.45 L 0,0 z" />
<path style="fill:#9cc374" d="M 0,-50 A 50,50 0 0 1 47.55,-15.45 L 0,0 z" />
</g> </svg>
```

The values `47.55` and `-15.45` will have to be calculated by means of `sin` / `cos` of the percentage-related angle times the radius (in this case: 20%, radius=50).

Comment: thanks, so that also mean I have to change the path argument (sweep flag, large arc flag) each time I go over 50% (180°) ? Because if I dont the arc wont look like I intend it to ? also need to invert the x y values it seems. For instance I want a 90% pie, in that case I need to invert cos(5,65487)*50 in a negative value (-40.45)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that is true. The two flags are the price we are paying for leaving out the centre coordinates of the arc in the path syntax.

Comment: I understand, yes. Not quite sure yet how am I going to animate it but it will be for sure harder than a simple stroke-dasharray with a css3 transition

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing this on 43.0.3 on Windows 7 also.

The way you are drawing your pie chart is a bit of a hack.  Most people would draw the pie sector as a filled path rather than trying to do it with a fat stroke.

Having said that, it does look like a bug in FF.  You should [report it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

I note however that if you change the `stroke-width` to `99px`, the issue goes away.  And it still looks okay on Chrome.

```css
svg {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

circle:nth-child(1) {
    fill: #4d80b3;
    stroke-width: 0;
}

circle:nth-child(2) {
    fill: #4d80b3;
    stroke: #9cc374;
    stroke-dasharray: 0, 314.159;
    stroke-width: 99px;
    transition: stroke-dasharray 2000ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0s;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <circle cy="100" cx="100" r="100"/>
    <circle cy="100" cx="100" r="50" style="stroke-dasharray: 62.8319, 314.159;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: yes the problem with the 99px stroke width is that there's a small spacing between the filled color and the base color (obviously). So it's not an ideal solution but it will most likely the one I chose if there's no other way. As for using a path that's a solution I didn't try, might need more js than my current version though, I'm not sure (never really did something like that before)

Comment: also there is another bug with that solution, the stroke dasharray animation gets very jumpy at some part. try loading a 90% circle on my codepen with 99px width stroke, you should experience it